# Symbolic Tensors replacing my normal tensors with Tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, symbolic-math, tensor

I have installed tensorflow-gpu recently instead of tensorflow-cpu, and my old code does not work anymore. When loading images, instead of having tensors of defined shape, it gives me "Symbolic Tensors", with shape (?, ?, ?) and no values in them, which I can't use to render my images, obviously.

I've tried looking things up, but I really don't get why my code does not work anymore, since the only thing I've changed is tensorflow.

```py
input_image = tf.io.read_file("./dataset/smth/smth/0000.jpg")
input_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(input_image)
input_image = tf.cast(input_image, tf.float32)
<tf.Tensor 'Cast_14:0' shape=(?, ?, ?) dtype=float32>
```

What I get:

> < tf.Tensor 'Cast_14:0' shape=(?, ?, ?) dtype=float32> +
>    "Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (truediv_1:0) to a numpy array"

What I want:

> < tf.Tensor shape=(x, y, 3) dtype=float32>

Also, here's the list of my devices:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 14952830314257248667
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 3225865420
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 6839329622363795927
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
]
```

Comment: What tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Tensorflow-gpu==15.0.*, because tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0 doesn't work at all, because of an "unknown error"